# How can I have the Maven output (or command line logs) with Python?

Tags: python, cmd

**Short version :** Is it possible to have the log gradually when we do a Popen in a loop?

**Long version :**

I had a bat file with a command line :

```
mvn clean -Dtest=LoadTest test
pause
```

I added this bat in a python script :

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen

os.chdir("../../../../tests")
for i in range(0,3):
    Popen(script.bat)
```

However, it's not good to put bat and python, I'm wrong? 
So I tested to add the maven command in my python script :

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen

os.chdir("../../../../tests")
for i in range(0,3):
    cmd= "mvn clean -Dtest=LoadTest test"+str(i)
    Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Seems working. But I whould like the log.. like the CMD

I tried :

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

os.chdir("../../../../tests")
for i in range(0,3):
    cmd= "mvn clean -Dtest=LoadTest test"+str(i)
    Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    output = p.stdout.read()
    print (output)
```

However, it print the log when my command is over so I cannot do a load test. 
Is it possible to have the log gradually like the CMD?

Like the bat do, Is it possible to open a CMD and set the command line? This can be useful for me.

EDIT : I tried to add a logfile too

```
cmd= "clean -Dtest=LoadTest test"+str(i) > LogTest.txt"
```

With my code, it's blocking the execution. Can I do it in parallele?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was more simple that I thought :

```
cmd= "clean -Dtest=LoadTest test"+str(i) > LogTest"+str(i)+".txt"
```

I added all my build resul in files. It trace all like the CMD does.

Thanks